# How edit PHTML template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

> How to Edit PHTML template in Magento 2?

I am trying to Edit PHTML template in Magento 2.

> First I **"Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront"** from Admin Panel.

Then I found that my template resides here "`public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml`". I went to that file and found below code there.

```
<div id="checkout" data-bind="scope:'checkout'" class="checkout-container">
    <div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
                 alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Loading...'); ?>"
                 style="position: absolute;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
        // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
    </script>
    <script>
        require([
            'mage/url',
            'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
        ], function(url, blockLoader) {
            blockLoader("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>");
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
        })
    </script>
</div>
```

I would like to edit PHTML template of Checkout Page. I would like to know   the location of the PHTML file of Checkout Page.

Comment: Update your question, with your exact requirement. Which thing you want to edit ?

Answer (score 2):

Copy the file to your theme. This will override the core template file.

New file should be located in below location where **vendor** and **theme** are your vendor name and theme name for custom theme.

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml`

This file can then be modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My question is Where is the HTML ? I am not getting any HTML code in that specific location/file.

Comment: That is html and a bit of php, i think a lot of the checkout it loaded via ajax however. What do you need to modify?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to modify which is loaded via ajax. Thanks

Comment: @harri , checkout page load using knockout js.

Comment: @Sarfaraj, Could you please help to find out the HTML Code while  checkout page load using knockout js. Thanks

Comment: @abu abu, sorry my friend i'm still working on checkout page but not find any exact solution about that how to customize checkout page with our custom data added to inside that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create HTML file or modify/override if exist from here.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/onepage.html

and copy it from here

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/web/template/onepage.html

**Note :-**  In this file the contents are come from different file using knockout.js so you have to modify that file using knockout js.

I hope you get it what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Sarfaraj. I am not getting any HTML file in your location. Thanks

Comment: please checkout my answer i have update it.
at this place "vendor/magento/module-checkout/web/template" you will get other html files also.

Comment: There is no `web` folder inside `vendor/magento/module-checkout/`. Thanks

Comment: this is not possible inside a core module of magento vendor module there is available web folder with js and template files.

Comment: Thanks @Sarfaraj. What do you mean in your comment ? You said in your Answer, I have to copy the HTML and then edit that. But first of all I have to get the HTML. I didn't get the HTML so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own theme at the location `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme` & put your template file into it at the following location

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml

Copy the Code from

> vendor/magento/module-Checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml

And paste it to your template file in your own theme & edit it as of you want it to look like.

> Note: You also need to take care of knockout js scripts as of in
>   checkout module of magento they used checkout for the template
>   rendering in frontend.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My question is Where is the HTML ? I am not getting any HTML code in that specific location/file.

Comment: The `phtml` file contains the html & php both the contents thats why it is saved as the `.phtml` So the thing you got into this file it is your html with some amount of php

Comment: There is no HTML content. Please see my Question first.

Comment: `<div id="checkout"....` it is your html content What you are exactly looking for?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am looking for HTML content which is adjacent to `<div id=""checkout....`. There is Form with the id `checkout`. I am looking for that. Thanks.

Comment: I think You got your answer right !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67165/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-abu-abu).

Comment: How can I edit the HTML Code ?